# open a sideloaded UWA app with parameters

Tags: windows, msix, appinstaller

I have created a wpf app and have been learning how to deploy it as a side loaded windows store app through an appinstaller package.

I now want to launch the app through a shell command with parameters. I did setup a protocol, but it doesnt seem to open the app. to make things worse I do not have permission to see the contents of the windowsApps folder it should be installed in.

can anybody explain how i can launch this app with an argument? Also can anybody explain how the file structure is setup inside the windowsApps folder?

Answer (score 0):

In the end i setup a protocol in the declarataions of my package manifest for my app to allow it to be opened through a url eg myapname:

[here is an explanation of how this works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation)

the full uri that is called is passed in the app parameters so i put custom handling in to allow me to pass waht i want in as a querystring

so for example i could call mayapp:?arg1=myvalue or myapp:localhost:80?myarg=myvalue